# Name of two stances and their weight distribution

Tags: tae-kwon-do, terminology, forms, stance

## Beomseogi

[An official video](https://youtu.be/Gr_Je2ZkgkI?si=hpIewWoEF3Q781ix&t=559) mentions the name of *Beomseogi* when the right foot is in front as *Oreun Beomseogi*. Also, in other times of the video, the naming is consistent:

- Right foot is front: *Oreun Beomseogi*.
- Left foot is front: *Oen/Wen Beomseogi*.

##### Weight distribution

In [another official video](https://youtu.be/6FUM1p6qqhQ?si=-o1ypAXjv65S2E4n&t=588), it's mentioned that the weight is distributed 9 to 1 by Beomseogi. The back leg takes 9 and the front leg takes 1.

[image: Screenshot: Beomseogi]

## Dwitgubi

[Another official video](https://youtu.be/ksSqKt0UkWo?si=9ZPoATBLbYukTjWt&t=528) mentions the name of the Dwitgubi when the right foot is back as *Oreun Dwitgubi*. So, basically:

- Right foot is back: *Oreun Dwitgubi*.
- Left foot is back: *Oen/Wen Dwitgubi*.

#### Weight distribution

Most of the body weight is on the back leg. Maybe the ratio is 4 to 1. I don't remember the exact ratio number.

[image: Screenshot: Dwitgubi]

## Question

I asked some instructors why the left/right name of Dwitgub is based on the back leg and not the front leg. They answered that's because the back leg takes a larger ratio of weight distribution.

Now, I wonder why the same principle is not applied to Beomseogi. I mean, why is Beomseogi named based on the front leg, not the back leg? Despite the fact that in Beomsegi back leg takes most of the weight load.

Comment: For posterity, I'll add that the apkubi (front stance) follows the same nomenclature as the dwitkubi, as does hakdariseogi (crane stance, which is also qualified by the foot on the floor).  Thus making the boemseogi the outlier where naming consistency is concerned.

Comment: Interesting - matching up with my ITF/Chang Hon knowledge - AFAIK weight bearing leg always denotes Wen/Oreun - in a 50/50 stance then it is front leg (and sitting stance doesn't have a left/right because that wouldn't make any sense) - these simplistic rules just aid an instructor - "Class left/right ABC stance" should have everyone in the same position provided they know the stance and weight distribution (without having to learn a rule per stance on which way to name it too)